# QTP to Generate QC Reports

Tags: qtp, hp-quality-center

I'm trying to automate reporting from QC by using QTP to export/save an excel file of the status of the tests on QC.  I'm trying to use QTP's object manager to perform each task, but I am running into two problems.  The first problem that I am encountering is getting QTP to recognize the different objects in QC.  The second problem comes when I try to run the scrip to login.  I keep receiving this error:

> Following client components were not downloaded successfully:
>   1 . CompStrgHelper.dll :
>   (Error 32) The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
>   Failed to open file for writing
>   2 . CompStrgHelper.dll :
>   Cannot load type library
>   3 . CompStrgHelper.dll :
>   Cannot register type library
>   Close all connections to Server and try again.

If anyone knows how to fix this, or just another way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to get the reports from QC in an automated format is to use VBscript or any scripting language and fire SQL queries to backend of QC. You can refer more on "how to create queries for test cases etc" from the blog [QTP Blog](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/how-to-retrieve-test-sets-test.html)

In VBscript or excel, you can use ADODB connection and recordset to connect to QC backend database

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK QTP ignores QC on purpose under the assumption that only HP QA would be interested in testing QC and for everyone else having QC open is part of the testing environment and not the AUT.

If you want to automate QC you should be using QC's API, [OTA](http://fijiaaron.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/updating-test-results-in-qc-using-the-qc-ota-api-explained/).